# coroutine object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, asynchronous, starlette

I am new to async python.

I have created a singleton object that supposed to load files from the filesystem

```
class AppResourceLoader(metaclass=Singleton):
    async def load_yaml(self, resource_filepath):
        async with open(path.join(path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)), 'resources', resource_filepath)) as f:
            return await yaml.safe_load(f.read())
```

`Singleton` is a plain metaclass

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(
                Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

I use this `AppResourceLoader` to upload file in the class constructor and access it later via getter

```
class ServiceCatalog(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, catalog_file):
        self.services = AppResourceLoader().load_yaml(catalog_file)

    def get_catalog(self):
        return self.services
```

This `get_catalog` method I call inside another class

```
class ServiceBrokerController(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.catalog = ServiceCatalog('catalog.yml')

    @ujson_route
    def get_catalog(self):
        return self.catalog.get_catalog()
```

Where `ujson_route` decorator looks like this

```
def ujson_route(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return UJSONResponse(func(args[0]))
    return wrapper
```

This `get_catalog` function of `ServiceBrokerController` is used by Starlette route object

```
async def on_startup_upload_catalog(request):
    ServiceBrokerController()

app = Starlette(
    debug=True,
    routes=[
        Route('/v2/catalog', ServiceBrokerController().get_catalog)],
    exception_handlers=exceptions.exception_handler,
    on_startup=[]
)
```

I run the test for `get_catalog` that looks like this

```
def test_catalog():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        response = client.get('/v2/catalog')
        assert response.status_code == 200

        services = ujson.loads(response.content)
        expected_services = AppResourceLoader().load_yaml('catalog.yml')

        # no changes
        assert deepdiff.DeepDiff(services, expected_services) == {}
```

But when I execute the test using plain `pytest -v` and it fails with the error

```
self = <starlette.responses.UJSONResponse object at 0x102d8f990>, content = <coroutine object AppResourceLoader.load_yaml at 0x102c8b9e0>

def render(self, content: typing.Any) -> bytes:
        assert ujson is not None, "ujson must be installed to use UJSONResponse"
>       return ujson.dumps(content, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
E       TypeError: <coroutine object AppResourceLoader.load_yaml at 0x102c8b9e0> is not JSON serializable
```

It worked before I made the `load_yaml` method asynchronous.

What is wrong? As far as I understand I need to put `await` somewhere because, from the error as I understand it returns coroutine but not the file data.

Comment: Maybe `return UJSONResponse(await func(args[0]))`

Comment: @sturcotte06 got `E       AttributeError: __aexit__  AttributeError` on `async with open` line

Comment: try to use an async version of open() like aiofiles, https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles